# STM32H755ZIT6 RCC Issue

Tags: stm32, arm, stm32cubemx, stmcubeide

I'm trying to set maximum frequency for M7 - 480 MHz and 240 MHz for M4.

when I'm setting them I always have RCC Power Regulator Voltage Scale 0 in RED and I can't change it.

[image]
[image]

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change it because 480 MHz requires VOS0 (Voltage Scale 0).

The program is just preventing you from doing things that are out of operating specs and will fail to work.

Comment: what is VOS0? can you tell me little bit more and how to fix it?

Comment: @Alatriste VOS0 is "Voltage Scale 0". To run the part at its max clock speed, that's the setting you have to use for the regulator.

Comment: @brhans I can't find VOS0 , STM32CUbeIDE does not show it, only Scale 2 and Scale 3

Comment: @Alatriste There is nothing broken so you cannot fix anything. If you want to run at other voltage scale settings than 0, then you can't run at 480 MHz but you need to change to run at lower frequency. But if you want to run at 480 MHz, you must use voltage scale 0, and you can't use the SMPS, you must use the LDO.

Comment: @Justme ok but when RCC settings is RED COLORED it means that something wrong right? or it's Just warning?

Comment: Seems I already set VOS0 by setting Power Regulator Voltage Scale 0 right, but why RCC still RED?

Comment: @Alatriste Maybe, but that should be asked from software manufacturer. If the software has a bug then report it. At least the CubeMX can warn and solve incorrect clock settings. You might have other incorrect settings so we can't really know why it's in red.